# run bash script with nice results in error

Tags: bash, nice, tmsh

I have a fairly long bash script.  I want to run it with nice

nice ./test1.scr

if I do not run the script with nice, it works great. But when I run it with nice.  commands being ran inside my script fail.

```
commandout=()
while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
do
    commandout+=("$line") # Append line to the array
done < <(tmsh show ltm pool $pool detail | grep -A5 "Ltm::Pool")
commandout+=(" ")
```

I get the following error if I run the script with nice

```
./test1.scr: line 269: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./test1.scr: line 269: `                        done < <(tmsh show ltm pool $pool detail | grep -A5 "Ltm::Pool")'
```

if I don't run the script with nice everything works ok.

I want to nice the whole script so I can get reduce impact to other processes while this runs

Comment: Does the `.scr` file start with `#!/bin/bash`? Otherwise it's possible that `nice` lauches it using `sh`. On many versions of Linux, `sh` is in fact `dash` and it doesn't know all the tricks `bash` knows.

Comment: You might want to use `readarray -t commandout < <(tush show ltm pool "$pool" detail | grep -A5 "Ltm::Pool")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't post as answer so I can't mark it as the answer.  But OMG I am soooo freaking dumb.

The script started with `#/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`  that fixed it.